# How to determine which network is used when the device connects to internet

Tags: java, blackberry

So far I have tried to do this by using `RadioInfo` class to verify which network is on and check if there are any changes in `RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsReceived()\Sent()`, but this approach is useless if more then one network is on. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Sorry for the spelling and grammar, English is not my first language.

Comment: Could you give a sign what are you trying to achieve? Even if wifi is enabled some of apps still could use radio connection

Comment: I want to adapt an Android app that measures internet traffic over mobile networks and WiFi. In Android i am using \TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes\ and \TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes\. In blackberry SDK all stats are encapsulated in \RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsReceived()\Sent()\ so now i need to determine which network is used when other apps are using the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your connection type after your URL.

```
public static String getConnectionString() {

String connectionString = null;

// Simulator behaviour is controlled by the USE_MDS_IN_SIMULATOR
// variable.
if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {

    connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
}

// Wifi is the preferred transmission method
else if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {

    connectionString = ";interface=wifi";
}

// Is the carrier network the only way to connect?
else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {

    String carrierUid = getCarrierBIBSUid();

    if (carrierUid == null) {
        // Has carrier coverage, but not BIBS. So use the carrier's TCP
        // network

        connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
    } else {
        // otherwise, use the Uid to construct a valid carrier BIBS
        // request

        connectionString = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID="+carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
    }
}

// Check for an MDS connection instead (BlackBerry Enterprise Server)
else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) {

    connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
}

// If there is no connection available abort to avoid hassling the user
// unnecssarily.
else if (CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE) {
    connectionString = "none";

}

// In theory, all bases are covered by now so this shouldn't be reachable.But hey, just in case ...
else {

    connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
}



return connectionString;

}

/**
 * Looks through the phone's service book for a carrier provided BIBS
 * network
 * 
 * @return The uid used to connect to that network.
 */
 private synchronized static String getCarrierBIBSUid() {
ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
int currentRecord;

for (currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++) {
    if (records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp")) {
        if (records[currentRecord].getName().toLowerCase()
                .indexOf("bibs") >= 0) {
            return records[currentRecord].getUid();
        }
    }
}

return null;
}
```

Once you writtent this code. use

```
con = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url + getConnectionString());
```

It will determine available network type .

Comment: thanks for you response and for the cod sample, but i am not trying to create a connection to the internet over an open network. I want to determine which network is used when other applications are using the internet.